# Android API level requirements

Tags: android

I've just downloaded the android sdk tools and launched "android" to install API packages.
By default it offers to install API level 19 which is fine to me. However, if later I'll want to develop an app with a lower API target (i.e. API 16) will I need to download that API as well or will API 19 be enough to compile for a previous target?
Thanks.

Comment: You also need API 16 when that's your target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to download the target API

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where is it documented?

Comment: No, sorry! But that's how it works, if you don't have an API, the compiler won't have anything to compile your code against

Comment: @lviggiani - see the [`<uses-sdk>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in Android docs.